# Элемент прикрепленный к бегунку

Tags: javascript, html, css, range

Есть бегунок. Нужно, чтобы его значение выводилось в блоке над ним, и этот блок следовал за бегунком, как на картинке. Подскажите, как такое реализовать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё зависит от того, на чём бегунок реализован. Может там уже всё есть

Comment: Одну минуту, позову гадалку, она код покажет и все сделаем.

Answer (score 5):

Шрифты уже не стал подбирать))...

```js
function fRangeChange() {
  let oRangeInput = document.querySelector('input[type=\'range\']');
  let oRangeLabel = document.querySelector('.range_label');
  oRangeLabel.innerText = '$' + oRangeInput.value;
  let nLabelWidth = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(oRangeLabel).width);
  oRangeLabel.style.left = parseInt(oRangeInput.value / 350 - nLabelWidth / 2 - 6) + 'px';
}
```

```css
.range_wrap {
  color: #c7c5d9;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  font: 13px 'Trebuchet MS';
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  height: 15px;
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 7px solid #93bb58;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #93bb58;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55) 1s;
  width: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range_wrap:hover>input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: 7px solid #93bb58;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px 2px #93bb58;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  width: 20px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #93bb58 0%, #93bb58 100%);
  height: 2px;
}

.range_label {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 0px solid #e9e8eb;
  border-radius: 4px;
  bottom: 40px;
  color: #1e1b67;
  font: bold 16px 'Trebuchet MS';
  left: -24px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: border 900ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.range_wrap:hover>.range_label {
  border: 2px solid #e9e8eb;
  transition: border 700ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
```

```html
<div class="range_wrap">
  <input type="range" class="volume" value="0" OnInput="fRangeChange();" min="1000" max="100000" step="1000">
  <div>$1000</div>
  <span class="range_label">$1000</span>
  <div>$100000</div>
</div>
```